# How to determine file extension is showed or not with boost filesystem

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-shell, boost-filesystem

My Question is simple. How me know that the given file path, its extension is showed on Windows explorer or not, using boost filesystem library.

I know answer with Shell:

```
     SHELLFLAGSTATE shellSettings = {0};

     SHGetSettings(&shellSettings, SSF_SHOWEXTENSIONS);        

     bool isShowed = ((shellSettings.fShowExtensions == FALSE);
```

But with boost filesystem not. Thanks.

Comment: As it's not something that is portable, it's not part of the Boost filesystem library. So the answer is that you can't do this through the Boost filesystem library.

Comment: Note that "Shell" is Explorer. So it makes sense: if you want to know whether Explorer shows something, ask Explorer.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg For that matter... What does this have to do with the file system?  It's basically an option for some external program; the extensions are always present in the file system.  (And `dir` will show them, regardless of what Windows Explorer does.)